# How to provide a default value for a metatype parameter in a Swift function?

Tags: swift, function, info.plist, function-declaration, metatype

In my app, I often need to access values stored in `Info.plist`. Instead of typing things like `Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String` every time, I created a nice wrapper.

The method for accessing values in `Info.plist` is declared like this:

```
static func get<T>(_ name: String, as type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[name] as? T
}
```

It works fine when called like that:

```
let appID = IPWrapper.get("APP_ID", as: String.self)
```

However, specifying the type every time is tiresome since many values in `Info.plist` are of type `String`). That’s why I’d like to provide a default value for the `type` parameter so I can omit it.

Unfortunately, the usual method of providing default values (adding `= default_value` in function declaration) doesn’t work: Xcode throws an error that says “Default argument value of type 'String.Type' cannot be converted to type 'T.Type'”.

```
// This code doesn’t work.
static func get<T>(_ name: String, as type: T.Type = String.self) -> T? { … }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**UPD**: Looks like overloading is the only way to fix this.

```
static func get<T>(_ name: String, as type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[name] as? T
}

static func get(_ name: String) -> String? {
    return get(name, as: String.self)
}
```

Comment: If the type can be passed as a parameter on call, I think one should able to provide a default value for the type. Not sure this isn't a bug.